# Преобразовать имя(название) переменной в строку(str)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть список с переменными. Например, одна из них называется `model_xgb`, при применении обертки `str`, получаю это:

> LGBMRegressor(bagging_fraction=0.8,...{много букв и символов} ....
> subsample_for_bin=200000", subsample_freq=0)

Мне нужно, чтобы ее имя - `model_xgb`, а не содержание, преобразовать в строку.
Как это сделать?

Comment: Так вы и так знаете название переменной в коде, в чём проблема? Без контекста непонятно.

Comment: имя=название переменной мне нужно использовать дальше для вывода. То есть в выводе на печать, например.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел, как сделать:

```
poisson_glm[-1].__class__.__name__
```

"poisson_glm" - переменная.
Вызывали ее из списка:

```
model = [ridge_glm, poisson_glm, poisson_gbrt]
```

Я похоже, не совсем, правильно задал вопрос. Сорри, начинающий питонер:)

Answer (score 2):

попробуйте так:

```
# функция перевода имени переменной в строку
def var2str(var, vars_data = locals()):
    return [var_name for var_name in vars_data if id(var) == id(vars_data[var_name])]


# проверка работы функции на локальных переменных
def test():
    your_variable = "test"

    for index in range(1):
        print(var2str(index, locals()))


# проверка работы функции на глобальных переменных
my_variabe = 1

test()
print(var2str(my_variabe))
```

если нужны только глобальные:

```
def var2str(variable):

    return [global_var for global_var in globals() if id(variable) == id(globals()[global_var])]


my_variabe = 1
your_variable = "test"

print(var2str(my_variabe))
```

можно еще так:

```
import varname

my_variabe = 1
your_variable = "test"

print(varname.nameof(my_variabe))
```

но у меня не установлен модуль `varname`, чтобы проверить код :(

Comment: Хм, толково! Но переменная может быть и не глобальной )

Comment: @CrazyElf, согласен, но для этого лучше использовать указанный выше модуль

Comment: Проверил модуль поставив на гугль колабе - работает

Comment: Хотя достаточно наверное поискать по очереди в глобалс, в локалс, в нон-локалс...

Comment: @CrazyElf, изменил код - посмотри как стало - теперь ищутся и локальные, правда пришлось немного изврата сделать :(

Comment: @CrazyElf, проблема поиска в локалс - это не твой локалс :) а функции `var2str`, поэтому локалсы надо передать функции, сама она не дотянется :(

Comment: Нда. Непросто всё, блин. Посмотрел исходники `varname` - там какая-то жёсткая магия вообще ))  https://github.com/pwwang/python-varname/blob/master/varname.py